# Reset app after crash?

Tags: iphone

I have an app that crashes and freezes, I pressed home button to get out of it but next time when I relaunch the app it brings up the splash screen and just sit there and does nothing. Seems like it somehow remembers the last failed state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After getting out of the app, try double-clicking home button to bring up background apps, hold finger on the app until app shakes and the red close button appears, and close it from there.  Then try reopening.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your phone! Wait for 5-10 seconds before you switch it back on!

If it still doesn't work, try re-installing the application!

Cheers